# I want to run a javascript code without using the browser but Vscode directly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wrote a code on the vscode but I want to run the code directly on the  vscode  for the output. After downloading the  "JUA HAN" as the code runner but is giving me this output. 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I wrote console.log("Hello world") on vscode. My expectation is to see Hello world on the vscode directly with the help of code runner.

Comment: have you installed NodeJS? https://nodejs.org/en/download/ If you already have, is the directory where it is installed in your system `PATH`?

Comment: do you expect VSC to come with Node, Python, Go, Ruby, Rust, PHP, C. C++,.... executables